# What is the position of UITabBarController's buttons?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am writing a tutorial for my app, and I am going to need the location of my TabBar's buttons for that. Since I am writing it to be for iPads and iPhones and would like to support any future versions of screens, I'd like to know how I can get to the underlying view's of the button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved!

```
int d;
NSArray* g = [myTabBarController.tabBar subviews];
for(d=0;d<=3;d++)
    NSLog(@"These are my subviews %@",[g objectAtIndex:d]);
```